# How to import module from main source code folder in a Jest test

Tags: javascript, jestjs, quasar-framework

My project's directory structure is like this:

```
my-project
+ src
| + pages
|   + Page1.vue
|   + Page2.vue
|   + commons.js
+ test
  + jest
    + __tests__
      + pages
        + commons.spec.js
```

How do I import `commons.js` into `commons.spec.js`?  Tried the following to no avail.  Error message says "Cannot find module '...' from 'commons.spec.js'".

1. `import ... from 'pages/commons'`
2. `import ... from 'pages/commons.js'`
3. `import ... from '/pages/commons'`
4. `import ... from '/pages/commons.js'`

If it matters, I'm actually using the [Quasar Framework](https://quasar.dev) with its [testing extension](https://testing.quasar.dev).

Comment: All of listed imports require to handle a path in a special way to resolve it from project root. If Jest wasn't configured for that, this won't work. Did you try relative paths?

Comment: I have not tried relative paths yet.  I'll check the Jest config.  I feel like using relative paths is wrong somehow...

Comment: I didn't check how Jest is configured in Quasar, but unless path alias is configured with moduleNameMapper, relative path is the only correct way to import modules that don't reside in node_modules, this is how module resolution is supposed to work in Node.